# Input capacitor in buck converter

Tags: capacitor, buck, flyback

I've chosen this [Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP11302) as starting point. [Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrk45/tidrk45.pdf?ts=1588543764945) the schematic. I'm using full wave rectifier instead.

I'm designing a buck converter with these requirements:

1. Input voltage: 120-690Vrms AC (three phase) 50/60Hz
2. Output: 50V/200mA (max)

To meet the high voltage requirements, the reference design uses a balancing network of three 400V capacitors, which may be expensive.

For my application following the controller datasheet, I calculated a minimum capacitance of 10 uF. However, I'm considering if I really need it. For example, this [another Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP10195#0) based on flyback topology doesn't use bulk input capacitors, just ceramic ones. But I think that applies if I always have three phase, right? If it happens that only two phases are available, then may I run into issues? What do you suggest?

Comment: Those capacitors aren’t that expensive. I found electrolytic capacitor 10uF, 400V, 20% tolerance for 84 cents on DigiKey.

Comment: Any solution with an industrial voltage range like that is not going to be trivially cheap...

Answer (score 0):

If you have three phase power, you always at have at least 50% your peak voltage available. Single phase power you go down to 0 volts at every zero cross so you need some amount of bulk capacitance.

**1 Phase:**
[image]

**3 Phase:**
[image]

Images from https://www.elprocus.com/difference-between-single-phase-and-three-phase-ac-power-supply/